# Two die throw and two expected output

Tags: probability

As an example, suppose we repeatedly roll two dice until we obtain either a
seven or an eleven. Of the 36 possible outcomes, 6 yield a seven and 2 yield an
eleven.

I can not understand why `6 yield a seven and 2 yield an eleven`?

I have an explanation for 7. If 1 die shows 6, to make the sum 7 another die should shows 1. But what is the meaning of 2 yield an
eleven?

I am more concern about the terms `6 yield a seven and 2 yield an eleven` rather than formula suggested in the link.

Comment: $11$ total can only be obtained here as $6+5,\;\;or\;\;5+6$

Comment: The answer did not clear the doubt what is the meaning of 2 yield an eleven?

Comment: [When two dice are thrown,] $2$ [of the $36$ outcomes] yield an $11$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$i+(7-i)=7$ here $i$ can take any value from $1$ to $6$.

However for $j+(11-j)=11$, we can only have $j\in \{5,6\}$ since otherwise if $j \le 4$, then we have $11-j \ge 7$ which is not a possible outcome for a dice.

Here is a table showing that shows the sum. I have only indicated the values when the sum is $7$ or $11$, you can check that the rest sum up to a different values and see that the sum along the anti-diagonal is constant. $7$ appears $6$ times while $11$ appears two times.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&1 & 2 &3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ \hline
1 &&&&&&7\\ 2&&&&&7& \\ 3 &&&&7&&\\ 4&&&7&&&\\ 5 &&7&&&&11\\ 6 &7&&&&11&\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Ok so, you are saying 6 yields 7 means we can get 7,  6 times and 2 yield 11 means we can get 11 2 times? Am I right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.